# Why were there no remains left in the "Killer Within" episode of The Walking Dead?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In one of the episodes of The Walking Dead, "[*Killer Within*](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Killer_Within)"

> Lori was eaten by a Zombie. Why wasn't there anything left of her body when Rick goes back to the room in "*[Say The Word](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Say_the_Word)*"? Even her clothes were devoured?

Comment: Welcome to this site! I took the liberty of changing your title. Please keep in mind overly broad titles such as "Walking Dead series" are not very helpful, since they don't tell readers what the actual question is.

Answer (score 4):

What we know:

- Lori died during childbirth.
- Carl claims to have killed Walker-Lori, but it was done off-screen if it ever happened.
- Rick went to recover the body but only found a walker that looked like it had very recently fed.

So, what happened to the body? Has it really been totally consumed, or is Lori a walker now?

No official answer has ever been given, but there *was* [a deleted scene](http://insidetv.ew.com/2013/08/16/walking-dead-deleted-scene-lori-zombie-season-3/) fueling the Walker-Lori theory.

The final version showed Rick talking to what appears to be a vision of Lori. The full version pulls back to show Lori as a walker.

But Walker-Lori *appears* to be wearing the white dress Live-Lori wears in the vision (it's cropped out of frame, but the straps are slightly visible), and neither Lori can be seen in the wide shot. Lori was not wearing the dress when she died and the white dress is likely just symbolic.

So is Lori really a walker out there somewhere? The other possibility is that she's not a walker at all. She's survived the c-section and is living/hiding somewhere. This would explain the lack of remains or clothes.

Both the Walker-Lori and Survivor-Lori theories are *extremely* unlikely, but without a body or remains of any sort, we have no conclusive evidence of Lori's fate.

Comment: Beyond being a poorly cropped version of the video, the "so-called" zombie-version of Lori does not seek to eat Rick. If this were reality, and not one of his hallucinations, she would have started eating him at the kiss if not before. It has been established that the zombie's humanity and / or care for loved-ones is gone. I find this to be non-evidence of Lori as a walker/zombie. It is evidence of Rick losing his grip on reality.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but there are apparently some people who cling to any theory.

Comment: I feel my answer is more accurate, but your answer is thoughtful and comprehensive so I won't vote it down.

Answer (score 3):

In the episode "[Killer Within](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Killer_Within)," Lori died during childbirth and Carl "killed" her.

I have not seen compelling evidence that Carl did not kill Lori after the birth. The look on his face as he is walking away after the gunshot tells the story. It seems that all the subsequent scenes are due to the madness that initiates Rick's further hallucinations via the phone-calls and such.

> [After watching his mother die while giving birth via C-section, a distraught Carl shoots her per her request to prevent reanimation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Grimes#Television_series)

Carl did what needed to be done and that fits with his character arc; after this he becomes more resolved. He was not fully raised in the pre-zombie world and wants to be responsible and respected for being wise beyond his age in this new reality. Carl is cold and his moral code is being formulated in a world not conducive to being a child or having a childhood. He is stepping up and the toll that takes on him shows.

As for Lori: *completely dead*, I see no ambiguity here.

The OP's question makes no sense. There is **never** a shot of the room Lori died in showing no corpse or clothing in the episode "Killer Within." Even the next episode does not provide compelling evidence of this. It doesn't make much sense.

**EDIT:** Since the OP's question has changed, I feel I should update this. The fact her clothes are not there is non-evidence. It's possible (but unlikely) that Carl missed her brain, or didn't shoot her at all. I think it's more likely the clothes were in another part of the cell or she was dragged away (less likely as it would have left a trail). The most probable ideas here are that the clothes are there, just not shown or the bloated zombie did eat them (seems unlikely as clothes are not flesh). This leaves the "clothes are there, just not shown" as most likely. When the producer says "he sees the stain of his wife and really nothing else," he seems to be talking about her as person. Why would he mention off-screen clothing when he didn't mention the knife right next to the stain? It's wasn't hyperbole, just an economy of words to drive home the devastation done to Rick. "He sees the stain, a bunk, a knife, some clothes, but little else," is not as conducive to the point he's making.

Comment: I'm unsure of the name of the episode, but yes, that did happen in the AMC version. It was a teenager that came to the prison with The Governor. Hershell (sp) was with Carl and told him not to shoot him because the kid was going to put down his rifle (or shotgun, I have forgotten which). Carl ends up blasting him in the head.

If I recall correctly, this happened after Lori's death, however.

Comment: I don't mean that incident, I mean the one where Carl sneaked out at night and killed someone he thought was a threat to the safety of the group. A kid who I think killed another kid. A delinquent type who already compromised the integrity of the group. And I seem to remember Hershel (or possibly someone else in the group) being privy to this info, but keeping it secret.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was "why wasn't there anything left?" And had nothing to do with whether or not Carl did or didn't... let alone why... or his thoughts about it... or his development as a character ;-) Lots of information, but very little of it is directed at the question asked.

Comment: I suggest the OP mentioned the wrong episode then or got characters mixed up. I rewatched it just for this question and am unsure what the question means.

Comment: [Walking Dead Wiki](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Carl_Grimes_%28TV_Series%29) has synopses of each episode Carl has appeared or been mentioned in, and a list of all the humans he has killed. The only thing close to what you're describing is when he killed [Jody](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Jody) in the woods after the Governor's assault on the prison.

Comment: I guess I got it mixed up, but one of the main group did kill someone in cold blood, in the middle of the night, for the safety of the group. It's hard to rewatch a series looking for one plot point.. ;)

Comment: Carol* killed an infected person in the middle of the night. (It may or may not have actually been Carol, but she has admitted to it, and accepted being forced out of the group for it)

Comment: Lori was killed during *Killer Within*, but Rick doesn't go to that room until the next episode, *Say The Word*. As original written, the questions wasn't exactly wrong, but it was less than perfectly clear. I've edited it to be more accurate.

Comment: That's not the part I'm thinking of. It's possible that it is just a bleed-over from the comic. SOOO much material to wade through to find the event I'm thinking of...

Comment: OK, then you're talking about [Ben](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Ben_%28Comic_Series%29). Ben was a little psychopath and Carl killed him in the comics. (It's possible that Ben is a template for the new girls on the show.)

Comment: **THANK YOU!!** Yes! Carl killed Ben. (I started reading the comic the day it came out. I'm surprised I don't mix up the stories more often.) I can stop fast-forwarding through the episodes now...

Comment: Watch the video I've added to the question. The Exec Producer comments on the scene saying Rick finds nothing but a stain and a zombie with bones in his throat, but no body of Lori.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my theory. Rewatch the episode and you will see that there is a blood trail leading out of the room with no obvious reason why. I think Rick dragged her body out already to be buried. He did not interact with the baby at all until he was done with the phone calls etc. I think he moved her body, and then broke down mentally and couldn't accept the grief of losing his wife. Part of him for that short time resented the baby and he saw the fat zombie and it looked pregnant, so him stabbing at its stomach was his anger at the baby for taking his wife away. 
It may be a bit screwed up but Rick was clearly not in his right mind after this.